# Property of isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $\phi $ be an isomorphism from G onto a group G'.Then For any element prove a and b in G, a and b commute if and only if $\phi(a) $and $\phi (b)$ commute.

Comment: Is $\phi$ an isomorphism? From which group to which group? (One needs to be precice about these things, because only then can one actually prove anything.) Also, what have you tried? You must have made _some_ attempts before you decided to go through the process of registering here and posting the question. Please edit your post and tell us exactly where you're stuck. And if you say you have no idea to even begin, then [I won't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I corrected my question.

Comment: Please do not repeat your [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014477/g-is-isomorphic-to-g-prove-that-if-g-is-cyclic-then-g-is-cyclic). It has been answered in the comments there already.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE! An isomorphism is merely a relabeling of the elements. Here, let $a,b\in G$. Then we have $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ and $\phi(ba)=\phi(b)\phi(a)$. So $a,b$ commute if and only if $\phi(a)\phi(b)$ commute.